# Homebrew updates and app self updates

Tags: homebrew, updates, homebrew-cask

How does homebrew/cask's updates work if the app auto updates itself.

Example: Chrome or Firefox

These two apps auto update themselves.

But what happens when you run a brew update?

Does it detect that it is already updated or does it check an internal list of apps it installed (misses that it is already updated) and reupdates the app>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[No](https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/issues/309). There is no `brew cask upgrade`.

Comment: So what is the current procedure to update casks? Uninstall and reinstall?

Comment: Yep, either use the app's built-in updater where applicable, or uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: The tracked Issue has been closed without adding an upgrade - they are going to be some restructuring of the project (see bottom of 'tracking' link, above, for more details)

Comment: `brew cask upgrade` is possible as of version 1.3.9

Answer (score 14):

The Homebrew Cask repository is technically a Homebrew Tap.

This means:

- It will pull down the latest Casks every time you issue the Homebrew command `brew update`
- You can check for outdated Casks with `brew cask outdated` and install the outdated Casks with `brew cask upgrade`

Most importantly for this question, applications that update themselves include `auto_updates true`. This means that these casks are ignored by `brew cask outdated` and `brew cask upgrade`. This can be overridden by adding `--greedy` to the command.

See the [Firefox cask](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/master/Casks/firefox.rb) as an example:

```
  url "https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/#{version}/mac/#{language}/Firefox%20#{version}.dmg"
  appcast 'https://www.macupdater.net/cgi-bin/check_urls/check_url_redirect.cgi?url=https://download.mozilla.org/%3Fproduct=firefox-latest-ssl%26os=osx'
  name 'Mozilla Firefox'
  homepage 'https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/'

  auto_updates true
```

Further reference is [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/master/USAGE.md).

Comment: For those who are looking, the 'auto_updates' is explained here: https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#why-some-apps-arent-included-in-upgrade

Answer (score 13):

`brew cask upgrade` is possible as of [version 1.3.9](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/releases/tag/1.3.9)

Comment: With the recents versions of Brew the correct syntax is `brew upgrade cask`

Comment: @LuckyStarr this doesnt seem to be the case. `brew upgrade cask` on v2.0.1 gives me `Error: cask not installed` whereas `brew cask upgrade` works.

Comment: `cask` is a valid `brew` command which in turn have the command `upgrade`. But if you would like to update a brew formula the correct syntax is `brew upgrade [formula]`.

Comment: This answer doesn't actually answer the question. To be complete it needs to say what happens if the app has auto updated and someone runs `brew cask upgrade`.

Answer (score 8):

Homebrew doesn't follow a new version of cask apps automatically, and you can leave such apps to their own auto updates as Homebrew intends to leave it to their own upgrade systems and e.g.

```sh
brew upgrade google-chrome
```

does nothing even when `google-chrome` has got a new update.

N.B. Now with [Homebrew 2.5.5](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/releases/tag/2.5.5), `brew cask` was deprecated and integrated to the normal `brew`.
If you want to do for cask explicitly, you may want `--cask`

```sh
brew upgrade --cask google-chrome
```

but all the same basically.

Should you want to follow the latest version on your Homebrew proper, you can run such a command as

```sh
brew upgrade --greedy google-chrome
```

Also you can check a diff between the latest and your local with

```sh
brew upgrade --greedy --dry-run google-chrome
```

This way however is mostly for cask apps without their own upgrade systems and you don't need these commands for those with the upgrade systems as long as you're not concerned about your version numbers on Homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to upgrade all outdated casks.

```bash
brew list --cask | xargs brew upgrade --cask
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `brew upgrade --cask --greedy`. Pay attention to the last argument, which means

```
$ man brew
...
   -g, --greedy
          Also include casks with auto_updates true or version :latest.
...
```

The thing is that this command doesn't update application but makes remove/install instead, which may leas to data and permissions lost. Unfortunately.

Also, there isn't way to get rid of those auto-update notifications.